# how to make a trigger in sql with GROUP BY? (oracle database)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make a trigger which sum the TOTALCOST based on the CUSTOMER_ID. And insert the data to the MAIN_ORDER table.

TABLE: ORDER_DETAIL

```
        ID |  CUSTOMER_ID | TOTALCOST 
          ------------------------  
          1 |    1000   | 50
          2 |    1000   | 50
          3 |    2000   | 200
          4 |    2000   | 200
```

TABLE: MAIN_ORDER

```
         CUSTOMER_ID | ORDER_PRICE 
          ------------------------  
           1000   | 100
           2000   | 400
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MOVEDETAIL
BEFORE INSERT ON MAIN_ORDER FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT ORDER_DETAIL.CUSTOMER_ID,ORDER_DETAIL.SUM(TOTALCOST)
INTO :NEW.CUSTOMER_ID,:NEW.ORDER_PRICE
FROM ORDER_DETAIL
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID;
END;
```

Comment: Hi, SO is not a general tutorial site.  If you google, "oracle triggers tutorial"  there are many, many examples.

Comment: what do you mean with "doesn't work"? Are you having an error? If so, which one? Or un unexpected behaviour? and if so, what did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping aside your trigger, if I understand well you have a table `ORDER_DETAIL` and you want to keep the data of a second table (`MAIN_ORDER`) aligned with every modification on `ORDER_DETAIL` data, so that `MAIN_ORDER` always contains the sum of `TOTALCOST` for each `CUSTOMER_ID` in `ORDER_DETAIL`.

If you want to do so with triggers, you have to handle every modification on `ORDER_DETAIL`, that is you need triggers for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` on `ORDER_DETAIL` ( not on `MAIN_ORDER`).

Given that you only have to keep informations aligned, I would suggest creating a **view** instead of handling a table with triggers.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_MAIN_ORDER
AS SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
          SUM(TOTALCOST) AS ORDER_PRICE
   FROM ORDER_DETAIL
   GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
```

The view always shows correct informations, with no need for triggers

```
SQL> INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL( ID, CUSTOMER_ID, TOTALCOST) VALUES (1, 1000, 50);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL( ID, CUSTOMER_ID, TOTALCOST) VALUES (2, 1000, 50);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL( ID, CUSTOMER_ID, TOTALCOST) VALUES (3, 2000, 200);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL( ID, CUSTOMER_ID, TOTALCOST) VALUES (4, 2000, 200);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM V_MAIN_ORDER;

CUSTOMER_ID ORDER_PRICE
----------- -----------
       1000         100
       2000         400
```

and no matter what you do on the table

```
SQL> DELETE ORDER_DETAIL WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 1000;

2 rows deleted.

SQL> SELECT * FROM V_MAIN_ORDER;

CUSTOMER_ID ORDER_PRICE
----------- -----------
       2000         400

SQL>
```